# Is UITextField+UIPickerView supported under Mac Catalyst?

Tags: uitextfield, uipickerview, mac-catalyst

In my iOS app I have a textfield with a picker view assigned to it's inputView. On iOS devices the picker view pops up whenever the user taps the textfield. The same code does not do that, however, when I run it as a Mac/Catalyst app. My debug effort so far shows that the picker view methods are not called at all, so if the Mac requires additional textfield delegate methods to take focus away from the Mac's keyboard? Any idea how to make this work on a Mac? A barebones example code is below.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate {
@IBOutlet weak var myTextField: UITextField!

var myPickerView : UIPickerView!
var pickerData = ["Alpha" , "Bravo" , "Charlie" , "Delta"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.myPickerView = UIPickerView(frame:CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 300))
    self.myPickerView.delegate = self
    self.myPickerView.dataSource = self

    self.myTextField.delegate = self
    self.myTextField.inputView = self.myPickerView

}

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return pickerData.count
 }
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return pickerData[row]
}
}
```

Comment: Did you ever get this working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like a bug in Mac Catalyst. Try using the `UIPicker` embedded in an `UIActionSheet`. [ActionSheetPicker-3.0](https://github.com/skywinder/ActionSheetPicker-3.0) is a ready-made solution. Show the `ActionSheetPicker` in `textFieldDidBeginEditing` of your `UITextField`.

Answer (score 1):

**ViewController**

```
class ViewController : UIViewController {

    // MARK: - Properties -
        
    var tableView : UITableView?

    var currentTextfield : UITextField?

    var gendersArray : Array<String> = ["Male", "Female"]

    var pickerView : UIPickerView?

    // MARK: - Lifecycle -

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // get the size of the iOS device
    
        let screenRect : CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds
        let screenWidth : CGFloat = screenRect.size.width
        let screenHeight : CGFloat = screenRect.size.height

        // add the picker view
    
        var pickerViewFrame = CGRect(x: 0.0,
                                 y: screenHeight - 162.0,
                                 width: screenWidth,
                                 height: 162.0)
    
        // set pickerview frame for macOS Catalyst

        #if targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)

        pickerViewFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 269, height: 240)

        #endif

        pickerView = UIPickerView.init(frame: pickerViewFrame)
    
        pickerView?.delegate = self
        pickerView?.dataSource = self

        // ... set tableview

    }

}
```

**UIAlertController Function**

```
// MARK: - UIAlertController -

@objc func textfieldInputAction(pickerView: UIPickerView, textfield: UITextField?) {

    print("textfieldInputAction")
    
    // alertController
    
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Title of Action Sheet", message: "", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.actionSheet)

    // reload components
            
    pickerView.reloadAllComponents()

    // add the picker to the alert controller

    alertController.view.addSubview(pickerView)

    // set height of Action sheet
    
    let height : NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: alertController.view!, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.height, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 350)

    alertController.view.addConstraint(height)

    // okAction
    
    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Done", style: .default, handler: {
        (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in

        // end editing
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {

            textfield?.resignFirstResponder()
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                UIApplication.shared.sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder), to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)
            }

        }

    })
    
    alertController.addAction(okAction)
    
    // popoverController
    
    if let popoverController = alertController.popoverPresentationController {

        popoverController.sourceView = textfield //to set the source of your alert
        
        popoverController.sourceRect = textfield?.bounds ?? CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0 )
        popoverController.permittedArrowDirections = [.down, .up]
                    
    }

    // present alertController
            
    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

**TableView**

```
// MARK: - Tableview -

extension ViewController : UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let cell : TextFieldCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TextFieldCell", for: indexPath) as! TextFieldCell
        
        // textfield
        
        cell.textField?.delegate = self
        
        cell.textField?.inputView = pickerView
                    
        return cell
        
    }
}
```

**UITextField Delegate**

```
// MARK: - UITextField -

extension ViewController : UITextFieldDelegate {
    
    func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

        print("textFieldShouldBeginEditing")
        
        #if targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)

        if textField.inputView == self.pickerView {

            self.currentTextfield = textField
            self.textfieldInputAction(pickerView: self.pickerView!, textfield: self.currentTextfield!)

            return false
            
        }
        
        #endif
        
        return true
        
    }
}
```

**UIPickerView Delegate**

```
// MARK: - PickerView Delegates -

extension ViewController : UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {
    
    // components
    
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        
        return 1
        
    }
    
    // rows
    
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        
        print("numberOfRowsInComponent")
                
        return gendersArray.count
        
    }
    
    // title
    
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
                
        return gendersArray[row]
        
    }
    
    // select row
    
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        
        print("pickerView: didSelectRow: \(row)")
        
        currentTextfield?.text = gendersArray[row]

        self.tableView?.reloadData()

    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: How did you got the frame magic numbers?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a hack, but let me share anyway. If you listen for the NSNotification `UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification`
this will fire before `-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField`
so you can set a BOOL to see if this method fires. If it doesn't, you can tell that you don't have a software keyboard, and then can show an alert controller or context menu, or however you want to handle it differently.

Answer (score 0):

On UIPickerViewMioPicker.swift

```
class UIPickerViewMio : NSObject, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {

private var uiTextField : UITextField?
private var oggetto = ["Uno", "Due", "Tre", "Quattro", "Cinque"]    

required init(uiTextField : UITextField?) {
    self.uiTextField = uiTextField
}

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return 5
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)
    {
    if let textField = self.uiTextField {
        textField.text = self.oggetto[row]
        textField.tag = row
    }
}
... omissis ...}
```

On UIViewController

```
@IBOutlet var textMioText : UITextField?
var uiPickerViewMioPicker : UIPickerViewMioPicker?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    ... omissis ...
    self.uiPickerViewMio = UIPickerViewMioPicker(uiTextField: self.textMioText)
    let pickerM = UIPickerView()
    pickerM.delegate = self.uiPickerViewMioPicker
    pickerM.dataSource = self.uiPickerViewMioPicker
    self.textMioText?.inputView = pickerM
    ... omissis ...
 }

 func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

    if textField == self.textMio {
        let picker = textField.inputView as! UIPickerView
        picker.isHidden = false
        if UIDevice.current.systemName == "Mac OS X" {
            let alertPicker = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.actionSheet)
            alertPicker.view.addSubview(picker)
            alertPicker.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: alertPicker.view!, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.height, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: picker.bounds.height * 1.1))
            alertPicker.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: alertPicker.view!, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.width, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: picker.bounds.width * 1.1))
            if let popoverController = alertPicker.popoverPresentationController {
                popoverController.sourceView = textField
                popoverController.sourceRect = textField.bounds
                popoverController.permittedArrowDirections = [.down, .up]
            }
            self.present(alertPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
            return false
        }
    }

    return true}
```